# How to fetch data as array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am fetching data from the database and the result is multiple rows but it is only showing 1st row in echo. please let me know where is the problem so that I can get all matched results.

```
public function review_email()
{   
                $date= date("Y-m-d");
                $this->load->model("site_model");
                $query = $this->db->get_where('review_email', array("date"=>$date));

                $row = $query->row();

                if (isset($row))

                {



                                    echo $name=$row->name;




                }


}
```

Comment: You have **too many unclosed questions**

Answer (score 1):

Try This --

```
public function review_email()
{   
   $date= date("Y-m-d");
   $this->load->model("site_model");
   $query = $this->db->get_where('review_email', array("date"=>$date));

   //$row = $query->row();
   $query->result();
   $row = $query->row_array();
   foreach ($row as $c) 
   {
     echo $c->name;
   }             


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code `$query->row();` means one row as an object, you also have `$query->result();` that will give you all the results as an object too, then `$query->row_array();` will give you one as an array, finally you have `$query->result_array();` which will give you all the results as an array.